# Catch on scroll when scroll is disabled with overflow: hidden

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to catch an event of scroll or touchmove with

```
$(document).on('scroll touchmove', function() {});
```

But that event is not working. Because i've used
`overflow:hidden;` How can i catch these events and use custom animation instead of classic scrolling.

Comment: event.type would let you catch it up.

Comment: May be this helps you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748042/detect-scrolling-attempts-in-overflowhidden-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```js
$(document).on('scroll touchmove', function() {
  console.log('scroll working...');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="min-height:1120px;"></body>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that i've used overflow: hidden; on the body

Comment: In order to work on scroll, you must have scroll on the page

Comment: Is it possible to catch mouse action like you could catch keypresses and then also a solution for touch movement

Comment: I've managed to catch the event with $(document).on('mousewheel touchmove', function(){      Now only i have to catch which side did it go (up or down) for both events.

Comment: check this for up, down mouse event http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872409/best-way-to-catch-mouseup-outside-of-mousedown-element

Comment: much apreciation Ranjeet

Comment: Thanks @Vlatko Murkovic. Happy coding :)